# Configuring Informatica Repository with Oracle 10g [Oracle not connecting]

Tags: oracle10g, informatica-powercenter

Oracle Details:-

- Oracle 10g Enterprise Edition
- Host running XP x32
- I use scott tiger for logging with SQL* Plus . **I dont provide any HOST STRING**. How can i setup Oracle to accept Host String ? i am asking this because i guess the problem is related to this
- IP : 192.168.17.132 , Hostname : vmxp1
- tnsnames.ora file:-

  GLOBALDB =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vmxp1)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = globaldb)
      )
    )

  EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SID = PLSExtProc)
        (PRESENTATION = RO)
      )
    )

  -Listener

  SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_LIST =
      (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\product\10.1.0\db_3)
        (PROGRAM = extproc)
      )
    )

  LISTENER =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.17.132)(PORT = 1521))
        )
      )
    )

Informatica details:

- i have successfully setup Client and server part of Informatica Powercenter 8.6 with the following config

http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/655/imagest.png

- when creating a repository from admin console i am not able to connect to Oracle

http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2152/262926281d2dcd78baa445d.png

tried different things in the host string field . also tried system account.

How to configure Oracle database for inf repository service.

Comment: The connect string in your second screenshot (`global.world`) is different to the database service name (`global`) in the first.  Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you need *at least* **two** database accounts to host this repository :

Power_Repository for the repository DB -

Power_Domain for the domain Configuration DB -

For Oracle, you MUST perform the following instruction:

Connect to DB:

Go to Start-> Run-> Type 'cmd'->Then put the same steps listed below:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Versión 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Voislav>cd\

C:\>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Dom Jul 10 23:50:07 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Introduzca el nombre de usuario: system
Introduzca la contrase±a:

Conectado a:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> CREATE USER Power_Repository IDENTIFIED BY Power_Repository
  2  DEFAULT tablespace users
  3  TEMPORARY tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited ON users;

Usuario creado.
```

Then confirm the connection:

```
GRANT CONNECT, resource, CREATE VIEW TO Power_Repository;
```

Now the same steps for Power_Domain., and is done.