# Cannot start Informatica services error in Windows 7 and Oracle 11g

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to install Informatica 8.6 server on my Windows 7 Home Edition Laptop with Oracle 11g. I am getting error message:

> "Cannot start Informatica services" EXITCODE: S.

There is a long description which says:

> "Use the error below and catalina.out and node.log in the server/tomcat/logs directory on the the current machine to get more information." .

When I checked catalina.out, the file is empty and node.log didn't exist in server/tomcat/logs.

Could you please let me know how to get rid of this error if have happened to come across and resolved that or know how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have downloaded a incorrect file in a x32 laptop., so my advice is to delete it., and make again the reconstruction in a 32-bits machine:

**Download:**

From [here](https://edelivery.oracle.com/)

First:

[image]

Then this 2 files:

[image]

**Repository Accounts:**

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402093/configuring-informatica-repository-with-oracle-10g-oracle-not-connecting)., that i posted few weeks ago.

**Server**

- Run the file1 pc861_win32_x86\install.bat and select the language and the option to install PowerCenter 8.6.1
- *You must* select the license key text file in File2>Oracle_All_OS_Prod.key

**Configuration**

- Domain name: Domain_OBIA7961
- Hostname: OBIA7961
- Node: node01_OBIA7961
- Port nº: 6001
- User= admin
- Pass= ***

In the advanced configuration put the *minimum* port 6005 and *max.* 6105

-- For more information go to Oracle official [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14847_01/bia.796/e14843/windows_ic.htm#BABCAJGA)